If $X$ is a manifold with $b_1(X)=0$ and no nontrivial finite-sheeted covering then $X$ is simply-connected
Let $X$ be a connected manifold with its first Betti number $0$, so that $H_1(X;\mathbb{Z})$ is torsion. Is it true that if there is no nontrivial finite-sheeted covering then $H_1(X;\mathbb{Z})=0$?
Maybe this is a group-theoretic problem asking: Let $G$ be a group with no subgroups of finite index, such that its abelianization is torsion. Then is the abelianization of $G$ trivial?
I'm asking this problem because it seems to be used in the answer of this question: 2-cohomology group of complex compact algebraic surface, but I can't see why this true.

Yes, you can think of this as the group theory question you stated:

Let $G$ be a group with no subgroups of finite index, such that its abelianization is torsion. Then is the abelianization of $G$ trivial?

The answer to this question is "yes". To see this, consider the abelianisation map $\pi:G\to G^{ab}$. Suppose the abelianisation $G^{ab}$ of $G$ is non-trivial and torsion. Then it has a finite index proper subgroup $A<_f G^{ab}$. Then $\pi^{-1}(A)$ is a finite index proper subgroup of $G$.
More generally, if $\phi: G\to H$ is a surjective homomorphism and $H$ contains a finite index proper subgroup $K$ then so does $G$, with $\phi^{-1}(K)$ working. The assumption that $G^{ab}$ is torsion is required above to ensure $G^{ab}$ has a finite index subgroup; in general, there exist abelian groups with no finite index subgroups, e.g. $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$.

Thanks, is it true that every torsion group has finite index subgroup? (Actually in the situation of my question $H_1(X;\mathbb{Z})$ is a finitely generated abelian group so it clearly has a finite index subgroup, but I'm curious in the general case.)

@blancket No. If a group contains a finite index subgroup then it contains a normal one. However, there are (finitely generated) torsion groups which are infinite and simple, and so by the previous sentence these torsion groups contain no finite index subgroups. Look up, for example, Tarskii monster groups.
